# httpOnly flag not working using Apache mod_headers

Tags: apache, setcookie, httponly, cookie-httponly, mod-headers

I've written [this rule](https://serverfault.com/questions/962184/cant-set-http-only-and-secure-cookies-in-apache) to add httpOnly flag to each cookie but the result was that[image].

What's wrong with the rule?
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ "$1;HttpOnly;Secure"

[EDIT]
I've tried to do this treatment at backend, but it's using servlet 2.4 and jboss4. But the [mininum required](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) is servlet 3.0

Comment: I'd *highly* recommend reserving setting any kind of cookies to done with scripting languages, not Apache. Apache is updated a *lot* less frequently than even slowly evolving programming languages. That being said there might be a way to do it though I just can't recommend coming to rely on Apache for everything.

Comment: which backend server are you using? This parameter is only recommended with SSL connector.

Comment: @Pandurang I've edited the post. It's java6 but the problem is that servlet version is 2.4

Comment: @John I've tried do it at backend but servlet version was a barrier

Comment: I program PHP, not Java though if the two are any alike instead of using PHP's `setcookie` function, specific to cookies, I would just use PHP's `header()` function instead. Surely Java has functions to let you completely define headers?

Comment: @John Indeed there are, but Apache seemed easier, that's why I made efforts on it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to edit JSessionID header? If yes then you need to use the same Exact name in Header. i.e

```
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

Comment: I want that every cookie be flagged as httpOnly

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146465/how-to-configure-jboss-4-0-to-make-session-cookie-httponly-and-secure to configure JBoss 4.0.* to make session cookie HttpOnly and secure.

Comment: I've tried to modify XML file ate Jboss4, no success

Comment: For which cookie you want to set HttpOnly? JessionId or any other? JBoss generates a default JSessionID cookie. are you generating cookie in code? If yes then you need to add httponly at the code level

Comment: for all cookies. But I'd rather to know why Apache strategy didn't work

Comment: Could you please use always and test. i.e `Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure`